# How to put the menu of the master page in the top right of the page? ASP.NET

Tags: html, css, asp.net

So I created a menu using a master page in `ASP.NET` but I have no idea how to put it where I want it to be in the top right of the page but not all the way up since I want to use a banner as well.
The code looks like this:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site1.master.cs" Inherits="NewWebsite.Site1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>    
<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">

    </div>
    <div id="header2">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <h2>Menu</h2>
        <table>
        <tr>
        <td><a href="HomePage.aspx"> Home Page</a></td>
        </tr>
            <tr>
        <td><a href="TopFighter.aspx"> Top Fighters</a></td>
        </tr>
            <tr>
        <td><a href="YoutubeVideos.aspx">Videos</a></td>
        </tr>
            </table>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
    </form>

    </div>
    <div id="left">

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and the css looks like this:

```
body {
    background-color:black;
    font-size:13px;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #333;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 16px;
    direction:rtl;
    border-color:cornsilk;
}
#header{
    height:120px;
    background:url("https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSljBA8SLU52gNwOjT0HYxWNs17EXF3ykPDNLaiwy0lsC4rx71w") repeat-x;
    direction:rtl;
    text-align:center;
    position:fixed;
}
#header2 {
    height:50px;
}
p {
    direction:rtl;
    text-align:left;
    color:brown;
    font-size: x-large;
}
HomePage picture {
    text-align: left;
}

table, td {
    border: 1px white solid;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 30px;
}

td {
    font-size: 23px;
}

td {
    padding-top: .5em;
    padding-bottom: .5em;
}

h1 {
    text-align: center;
}

img {
    padding: 5px;
}

video1 {
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
}

video2 {
    text-align: left;
    position: relative;
}

#video1 {
    position: static;
    text-align: left;
}

#video2 {
    position: static;
    text-align: left;
}

h3 {
    text-align: left;
}
```

Just so you understand this is a school project and I am really not familiar with `ASP` so I would like a really simple explanation, this is my first post here as well so if I forgot to add something please tell me and I will edit this.

Comment: To start, put all the html inside the form tags. body - form - your html. ContentPlaceHolder1 will also be in the form tag, as it is now.

Comment: Your css needs updating too -- HomePage; video1; video2.

Comment: @wazz First of all what do you mean by updating my css? The second thing that I want to ask is how can I control where the menu is? Because right now it is the top right of the screen and I would like to lower it a bit but I have no idea how.