# How to change the master page menu location in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

So I need to do my school project which is building a website using asp.net and including a master page. 
Now I kind of got stuck since My menu isn't where I want it to be (I pointed where I want it to be using paint), I have no idea what I'm doing wrong so if someone could tell me how to change the menu location and why it didn't work for me I will be very glad.

```
 this is the video page code


`<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site1.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Videos.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.Videos" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
    <link href="StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <style type="text/css">
        .auto-style1 {
            height: 298px;
            margin-top: 0px;
        }
    </style>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <h1>Videos</h1>
    <p>This page will show avideos about Muay Thai techniques, trainings and also other intresting content</p>



    <div id="video1">
    <iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/6Glyrl0-cSk" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen class="auto-style3"></iframe>
    </div>
    <h3>Buakaw training</h3>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
        <div id="video2">
    <iframe width="420" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Mf1Ch8mJ464" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen class="auto-style1"></iframe> 
      </div>

    &nbsp;











</asp:Content>`
```

this is the css code:

```
`body {
            background-color:black;
        font-size:13px;
        font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        color: #333;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        line-height: 16px;
        direction:rtl;
        border-color:cornsilk;
        }
        #header{
            height:120px;
            background:url("https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSljBA8SLU52gNwOjT0HYxWNs17EXF3ykPDNLaiwy0lsC4rx71w") repeat-x;
            direction:rtl;
            text-align:center;
            position:fixed;


        }
        #header2
        {
            height:30px;

        }


        p
        {
            direction:rtl;
            text-align:left;
            color:brown;
            font-size: x-large;
        }
        HomePage picture
        {
            text-align:left;
        }
        table,td
        {
            border:1px white solid;
           border-collapse:collapse;
           border-spacing:30px;


        }
        td
        {
         font-size:23px
        }
        td
        {
        padding-top: .5em;
        padding-bottom: .5em;
        }
        h1
        {
            text-align:center;
        }
        img
        {
            padding:5px;
        }
        video1
        {
           text-align:left;
           position:absolute
        }
        video2
        {
        text-align:left;
        position:relative;
        }
        #video1
        {
            position:static;
            text-align:left;

        }
        #video2
        {
        position:static;
        text-align:left;
        }
        h3{
            text-align:left;
        }`

 and this is the master page code:

    ` <%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site1.master.cs" Inherits="NewWebsite.Site1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">

    </div>
    <div id="header2">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <h2>Menu</h2>
        <table>
        <tr>
        <td><a href="HomePage.aspx"> Home Page</a></td>
        </tr>
            <tr>
        <td><a href="TopFighter.aspx"> Top Fighters</a></td>
        </tr>
            <tr>
        <td><a href="YoutubeVideos.aspx">Videos</a></td>
        </tr>
            </table>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
    </form>

    </div>
    <div id="left">

    </div>
</body>
</html>`
```

[Where I want to put my manu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6F7FM.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to put the menu of the master page in the top right of the page? ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48011040/how-to-put-the-menu-of-the-master-page-in-the-top-right-of-the-page-asp-net)

Answer (score 0):

i just dont know why you are not using bootstrap ?
if you will usew bootstrap it would be easy to place content any where you want with a responsive design  Like

just make a a row with 2 divs inside that like

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row col-sm-8">
  Now place your Video Content here like :
    <h1>Videos</h1>
    <p>This page will show avideos about Muay Thai techniques, trainings and also other intresting content</p>



    <div id="video1">
    <iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/6Glyrl0-cSk" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen class="auto-style3"></iframe>
    </div>
    <h3>Buakaw training</h3>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
   
    </div>
    <div class="row col-sm-4">
    And place you navigation here like :
   <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">  
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Run this Snippet in a full page view you will find out how to adjust more and do stuff that you want

Comment: What is exactly bootstrap? Just so you know I don't really have that much knowledge or experience in programming so if you can I would be happy if you were to explain to me what you did here

Comment: bootsrap is an online library which you can download or use online two with just links in your header what you have to do is to just  provide those links in the head section of your page and then you will be able to to use its components which provides a responsive design for yor websites 
go to [Introduction](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/)